# Code signature in oci8.so not valid with SIP enabled in Macos Mojave

Tags: php, oracle, code-signing, pecl, oci8

I installed oci8 via PECL on Macos Mojave, for use with PHP and I had it all working, until I enabled SIP again.
Now I get the following error when I try to use oci8:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/oci8.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/oci8.so, 0x0009): code signature in (/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/oci8.so) not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed. in Unknown on line 0

I googled my eyes out, but the only 'tips' I could find, are to disable Apache and PHP and install it all again via brew. Well, that is not an option. Also I found others who simply signed dylibs with codesign. But this is an .so and I don't know if it can be codesigned. Furthermore, I do not have an Apple Developer account, so `codesign -s MyID` will not work, AFAIK.

So my question is : does someone have an elegant solution to my problem?

I'm running Macos 10.14.6, PHP 7.1 with reinstalled versions of PEAR & PECL, Xcode, Xcode headers in /usr/include (for PECL), Oracle in /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_3/.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Put the Instant Client libraries in `~/lib` or `/usr/local/lib`.  You'll probably need to do the latter. See 3.5.4 in https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#instosx

Comment: They are there already. I already performed those steps. That's why it works - with SIP disabled. My problem seems to be the code signing problem. I don't understand why the oci8.so wasn't signed properly when I created it with PECL.

Comment: Works for me with SIP (though I am running Apache in my home dir, and building OCI8 from source).